# Create a RecyclerView equal space horizontal in portrait and landscape?

Tags: android

> Create a RecyclerView equal space horizontal in portrait and landscape ?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
           
ArrayList<DashModel> dashModelArrayList;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
DashAdapter dashAdapter;

protected void onCreate (Bundle saveInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layoutgirdm);
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv1);

dashModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
String heads[] = {"jobs","profile","message","apple","setting"};
String subs[] = {"12 news","75 complete","2 new messages","3pplie","edit","set pref"};
int images[] = {R.drawable.ic_lock_24px};

DashModel dashModel = new DashModel();
for(int count = 0 ; count < heads.length; count++){
dashModel.setHead(heads[count]);
dashModel.setSub(subs[count]);
dashModel.setImage(images[0]);
dashModelArrayList.add(dashModel);
}
    
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinarLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
dashAdapter = new DashAdapter(dashModelArrayList);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(dashAdapter);
}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Call this method from your ViewHolder constructor

```
 protected void onViewHolderCreated(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.binding.rlContent.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = totalWidth / getItemCount();
        viewHolder.rlContent.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Comment: public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items,parent,false);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = totalWidth / getItemCount();
        view.setLayoutParams(params);

        return new ViewHolder (view);
    }                                                                       it is not work

Comment: can you send me files, where you put these lines?

Comment: here is [link] we.tl/t-FxR2t1HsMP [link]

Comment: send me your adapter code, I will add these lines, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: here is adapter code [link] we.tl/t-QPwE7NINjW [link]